# Exclude Records Based on Criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to exclude the record:

1. If a customer bought "Shoe" and "Hat" on the same day, exclude the record with "Hat".
2. If a customer bought "Shoe" and "Cloth" on the same day, exclude the record with "Cloth".

Here is the sample data:

```
create table tbl
(
  Customer  varchar(5),
  Day date,
  Product  varchar(5),
  Cost  decimal(10,2)
);

insert into tbl values 
('A',       '1/1/2019',      'Shoe',        10.00),
('B',       '2/4/2021',      'Hat',          10.00),
('B',       '5/8/2018',      'Shoe',         10.00),
('C',       '6/6/2020',      'Hat',         10.00),
('C',       '11/9/2021',      'Cloth',       10.00),
('E',       '7/2/2020',      'Hat',        10.00),
('A',       '7/5/2022',      'Hat',       10.00),
('C',       '6/6/2020',      'Shoe',        10.00),
('A',       '1/1/2019',      'Cloth',        10.00),
('E',       '7/2/2020',      'Shoe',       10.00);

select *
from   tbl
group by Customer, Day, Product, Cost
order by Customer, Day
```

Here are the expected results:

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self join to your shoe criteria and make sure it is not there, like this:

```
select tbl.Customer, tbl.Day, tbl.Product, tbl.Cost
from   tbl
left join tbl as shoe on tbl.customer = shoe.customer and
                    tbl.day = shoe.day and
                    shoe.product = 'Shoe'
where not (tbl.product in ('Hat','Cloth') and coalesce(shoe.product,'') = 'Shoe')
group by tbl.Customer, tbl.Day, tbl.Product, tbl.Cost
order by tbl.Customer, tbl.Day
```

Comment: What is the point of GROUP BY since no aggregation is done?

Comment: @forpas -- the OP had it in his original post so I figured he wanted it there for a reason.  You are right, probably not needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1_c    customer,
       t1_d    date_,
       t1_p    product,
       t1_cost cost
  FROM (SELECT t2.product  t2_p,
               t2.day      t2_d,
               t1.product  t1_p,
               t1.day      t1_d,
               t1.customer t1_c,
               t1.cost     t1_cost
          FROM tbl t1
          LEFT JOIN tbl t2 ON t2.day = t1.day
                          AND t2.customer = t1.customer
                          AND t2.product = 'Shoe') t
 WHERE (t2_p IS NOT NULL
   AND t1_p = 'Shoe')
    OR t2_p IS NULL
```

Comment: sql server requires an alias on sub-queries.  I believe it is part of the standard also.

Comment: also shoes will be excluded since they join to themselves

Comment: @Hogan Oh.. :)  so probably not :D.

Answer (score 0):

You want all the rows with 'Shoe' and only those rows with other products if at the same day the customer hasn't bought a 'Shoe'.
Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tbl t1
WHERE t1.Product = 'Shoe'
   OR NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT *
     FROM tbl t2
     WHERE t2.Customer = t1.Customer AND t2.Day = t1.Day AND t2.Product = 'Shoe'
   );
```

Or, if there are more products than the ones included in the sample data:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tbl t1
WHERE t1.Product NOT IN ('Hat', 'Cloth')
   OR NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT *
     FROM tbl t2
     WHERE t2.Customer = t1.Customer AND t2.Day = t1.Day AND t2.Product = 'Shoe'
   );
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7e5ebc411a5a9b7c3cf61cc7b196a4d8).

Comment: Not exactly the stated requirements.  For example a row with 'Shirt' with shoes would be ok.  (Because shirt and shoes required to enter).  But your query would exclude it.

Comment: @Hogan if there was a Shirt then the code would include it in the requirement. See my 2nd query.